# how to use $and in find query in sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

```
var fn=req.param('searchfn');
var ln=req.param('searchln');

User.find({and: [{FirstName: fn },{LastName: ln }]}).done(function(err, beneficiary) {
  if(err)
    return next(err);
  if(!beneficiary)
    return next();
  res.json(beneficiary);
});
```

It returns `[]`.
Although it returns list of value while executing the query with same criteria in mongodb.

Comment: All mongodb queries are implicitly an `$and` query. You do not need this operator unless you need more than one condition to compare on the same field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every find-criteria can be a json with more than one element:

```
User.find({FirstName: fn, LastName: ln}).exec(function(err, beneficiary) {
  if(err)
    return next(err);
  if(!beneficiary)
    return next();
  res.json(beneficiary);
});
```